# Convert string data to date format in pandas dataframe (type str: day mount)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a very non-standard, as it seems to me, data set from an open source. It is represented as strings, format: `day month`. For example: `11 January`. There is no year, but I know that this data at the source starts from 2021 (as evidenced by some chronological history, but let's skip this moment). The problem also arises because this data is written in Russian, which further complicates, as it seems to me, the use of `datetime`.

What I have now:

```
    date        vaccinated person   fully vaccinated person     
1   30 апреля   220 000             206 000 
2   14 апреля   220 000             NaN 
3   28 февраля  215 924             NaN 
4   15 февраля  213 380             141 200 
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
57  24 января   1 200               NaN 
58  19 января   1 002               NaN 
59  18 января   942                 NaN 
60  14 января   870                 NaN 
61  11 января   750                 NaN
```

What do I want to get as a result:

```
    date        vaccinated person   fully vaccinated person 
1   2022-05-30  220 000             206 000 
2   2022-04-14  220 000             NaN 
3   2022-02-28  215 924             NaN 
4   2022-02-15  213 380             141 200 
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
57  2021-01-24  1 200               NaN 
58  2021-01-19  1 002               NaN 
59  2021-01-18  942                 NaN 
60  2021-01-14  870                 NaN 
61  2021-01-11  750                 NaN
```

Exaple source, where did i get the data for multiple regions: https://gogov.ru/covid-v-stats/msk#data

Update, translated the column with dates into English, but the questions of how to attach the correct year to them and convert them to date format remain open.

```
    date                vaccinated person   fully vaccinated person     
1   April 30            220 000             206 000 
2   14th of April       220 000             NaN 
3   28th of February    215 924             NaN 
4   February, 15        213 380             141 200 
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
57  January 24          1 200               NaN 
58  January 19          1 002               NaN 
59  January 18          942                 NaN 
60  January 14          870                 NaN 
61  January 11          750                 NaN
```

However, the translation leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Your data is ambiguous in years, how would you know that `11 января` is `2021-01-11`, not `2022-01-11`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang, good point, but fortunately I know this, this data reflects vaccination statistics and there is a record of what year it started exactly.

Comment: That was just an example, the question applies to other rows as well, without the year information **in the data**, pandas or any other library will assume **one default** year.

Comment: @Quang Hoang, I looked through the entire portal and regions with data, got all the data using parsing. Yes, they all start at the same age

Comment: @Quang Hoang, while I have the following idea, translate the date column into English, and then try to properly consider the functionality ```datetime```)